# Linear regression model for subset within dataset?

Tags: r, model, regression

I have a dataset that contains over 300 entries of different vehicle models, some cars, some bikes, and 10+ rows of characteristics (colour, size, mpg, etc).

How can I fit a logistic regression model to predict the probability that the 'mpg' of the vehicle correlates to it being a car, if cars/bikes aren't actually categorised within the dataset (though it is ordered i.e. only columns 1:200 are cars and 201:300 are bikes).

I would think I need to create a subset of my dataset but I can't figure out how to correlate a characteristic from the original dataset with a subset.

Apologies if this is poorly explained, appreciate any help!

Comment: it is really poorly explained. can you provide an example of your dataset and the code of what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should restructure your dataframe first (you may want see vehicle models in rows and characteristics in columns. I suggest using `t()` as a transpose function, then add another column with dummy variables (1 if car type is car and 0 if not). Now you are able to regress car type on mpg by using `glm()` if you want to fit a logistic regression or `lm()` for linear regression.